# Batch IF/Else statement not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

What is wrong with the following code?

```bat
@echo off
:fromFirst
set /p TN="Enter your name: ":
echo %TN%
set tim= %TIME%
echo %tim%
set det=%TN%%tim%
echo %det% >> List.txt
set /p ch="Do you want to continue(y/n):" :
IF "%ch%"=="y"
(
goto :fromFirst
)
ELSE(
exit
)
```

Could you please help me in solving this?

Comment: Insert code as text, not as image! And read the help of [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) by typing `if /?` into a command prompt window!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to `set` up variable in **det** when you have already setup the same in earlier in **TN** for *name* **tim** for *time*?

The below batch should work fine:

```
@echo off
:fromFirst
cls
set /p TN=Enter Your Name  :
echo %TN%
set tim=%TIME%
echo %tim%
echo %TN% %tim% >>List.txt
set /p ch=Do You Wish to Continue? (y/n)
if "%ch%"=="y" goto fromFirst else exit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```